# Draw simple timeline with D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization, timeline

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: Timeline]

In this example, I have a starting date (1º Jun 2011), an ending date (1º Jul 2012) and multiple events between this range.

Each event is related to one day of the calendar (although it is possible to have many events on a single day).

This data is fetched from a MySQL DB.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I recently had to do something similar. I ended up writing a d3 plugin that could handle this case among a few others. https://github.com/jiahuang/d3-timeline

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm pretty new to D3 as well, but I hope it's useful.

Comment: I had to make some changes in the code, but your plugin was exactly what I needed. Thanks and sorry for the late response, I was busy with another stuff.

Comment: @azeós could you share your modifications with the class? I am very curious.

Comment: @randomblink It was for an old and dead project. I'll search through the files and see if I can find it.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to accomplish this with a [time scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales) and an [axis](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-axis)

[Scott Murray](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/) has a really good set of tutorials that culminates in one for [axes](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes/)

Just think of your time line as a 1-dimensional scatterplot with a time scale.

Comment: Is there a tutorial for D3 tailored to 5 year olds? I need something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to develop similar visualization and found on Github [timeknots](https://github.com/alangrafu/timeknots) component based on d3.js.