# D3 Timeline with Links for Nodes

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, timeline

I'm trying to build a timeline like this one:
[image]

Which comes from this question:
[Draw simple timeline with D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201749/draw-simple-timeline-with-d3)

However, I'd like the individual nodes to be hyperlinks.

Comment: add a click event to them and redirect http://bl.ocks.org/WilliamQLiu/76ae20060e19bf42d774

Comment: Hi, please post some code of what you've tried so far.